# Connecting Blob Storage to a Synapse Workspace with Public Network Workspace Access Disabled

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I'm trying to connect blob storage from my RG storage account to the Data tab in my synapse workspace, but I get the following error: "The public network interface on this Workspace is not accessible. To connect to this Workspace, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network or enable public network access for this workspace."

Public network access to my workspace must be disabled for company reasons. I made private endpoint connections on my synapse resource to Dev, Sql, and Sql-On-Demand, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Azure Synapse -> Manage -> Managed private endpoints -> +New and add private endpoints.

[image: Ref1]

Accessing blob storage : If you already created linked service the follow below image. If not, please created and follow this [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services?tabs=data-factory) for creating linked service.

Fastest way to access Azure blob storage

[image: Ref1]

For for information follow this [reference](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/azure/query-blob-storage-sql-using-azure-synapse/) by Dennes Torres.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I needed my storage account to be gen2, so it's visible now. But I'm unable to create managed private endpoints from my workspace. I get the same error in my post.

Also, I'm having problems with my sql pools. Builtin's status is 'unavailable' and I get this error when I try to run scripts on a dedicated pool: Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes. To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network.